# Finding matching data in three different text files

Tags: java

I'm trying to find matching data in three text files, i'm new at programing, and not really sure what to do. I have 3 different text files, in each text file there are a bunch of credit card numbers. I am trying write a program that will numbers that are in all 3 files. I tried putting them in arrays and sorting from there, but it didn't work. I can't seem to figure out how to do this. The code below is the farthest im able to come, but its not giving me any output.

```
 BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("creditCards1.txt"));
String num1;
while ((num1 = br1.readLine()) != null) {
 BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("creditCards2.txt"));
        String num2;
        while ((num2 = br2.readLine()) != null) {

            if (num1 == num2){
                System.out.print(num1 + " Was used in 2 stores");
```

Comment: *"Here's what I have so far"* is not an acceptable question. Clearly identify your problem (and also provide sample data).

Comment: You will likely have to start indexing your data.  Do a little searching on HashSets and HashMaps.

Comment: You could make a third loop, but i think efficiency would plummet. May have to look at other data structures to store these in for comparison.

Comment: You don't want to read the second text file for each line in the first text file. And that will get even uglier if you get a third file into the picture. You should read each file and store the data in a `Set`, and then as you read subsequent files, you can check whether the items are already part of the set.

Comment: Of course it is difficult task but at first try this: 

 1. Get next word or name in first file.
 2. Find current word or line in tho others

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific on how it has to work. this seems like it should work but it will be really really slow this way. because it has to match every line in one document with every line in another. What you might want to do is split the lines on "." if you want to compare sentences.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to used 3rd party solution to solve this.

First is to import those file in Excel and find duplicates. Second get familiar with [Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/)

And note that object in java are compared using `equals(Object)` method.

So instead of  `num1 == num2` you should have `num1.equals(num2)`

Comment: Actully i didnt need to do the excel thing!! num1.equals(num2) Worked!!! THANK YOU!